# How to login directly in Auth0 without redirect universal login page?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, auth0, auth0-lock

I'm working on Auth0 integration, i successfully integrated Auth0 SDK in my Swift project, but i want to implement direct login from my app with out redirect into Auth0 universal login page.

I studied mobile login flow here (https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/mobile-login-flow
).

I implemented Auth0 login in iOS Swift it's working. But i want direct login.

See my screens

When we click login in my app it shows pop up. 
[image]

Click continue it will open Auth0.com page (I don't want this page, i want direct login with out this page How?)

[image]

I don't want this page, i want direct login with out this page through mu app login page, How?.

**Is it possible?.**

For this i followed this link https://auth0.com/docs/flows/guides/mobile-login-flow/add-login-using-mobile-login-flow and implemented **code_verifier and code_challage.** But when i implement **Authorize the User** it's given **html response**.

My code is:

```
func codeVerifier() {
    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 32)
    _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, buffer.count, &buffer)
    let verifier = Data(bytes: buffer).base64EncodedString()
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "$_")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
        .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

    print("Code_Verifier : \(verifier)")

    codeChallenger(verifier: verifier)
}

func codeChallenger(verifier:String) {
    // Dependency: Apple Common Crypto library
    // http://opensource.apple.com//source/CommonCrypto
    guard let data = verifier.data(using: .utf8) else {

        return
    }

    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &buffer)
    }
    let hash = Data(bytes: buffer)
    let challenge = hash.base64EncodedString()
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "$_")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
        .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

    print("Code_Challenger : \(challenge)")

    authorizwTheUser(code_challange: challenge)
}

func authorizwTheUser(code_challange:String) {

    let url = "https://domain.auth0.com/authorize?"

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpMethod = "GET"

            print("URL : \(request)")

    let parameters = "response_type=token&code_challenge=\(code_challange)&code_challenge_method=S256&client_id=&redirect_uri=com.myappname.Auth0DemoSwift://domainname.auth0.com/ios/com.domainname.Auth0DemoSwift/callback&scope=openid profile&state=xyzABC123x"

    request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

    print(parameters)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else { // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
                }

                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 { // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                }

                                            // If Response is in String formate
                                            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                                            let dictionary = data
                                            print("dictionary = \(dictionary)")
                                            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString!))")

                do {
                    let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]
                    print(response!)

                    let res = response!["Response"]
                    let status = res!["status"] as! String

                    if status == "SUCCESS" {

                    } else {

                    }

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the consent screen and redirection to auth0 hosted login page, you can use authentication API with [password-realm grant type](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant#realm-support). The disadvantages are:

- NO SSO
- You need to develop your own UI
- Easy to use brute force attack (Enable brute force protection in the dashboard)

As described:

> The Authentication API exposes AuthN/AuthZ functionality of Auth0, as well as the supported identity protocols like OpenID Connect, OAuth 2.0, and SAML. We recommend using our Hosted Login Page but if you wish to build your own UI you can use our API endpoints to do so. However some Auth flows (Grant types) are disabled by default so you will need to enable them via your Auth0 Dashboard as explained in this guide.

**Sign In:**

```
Auth0.authentication()
     .login(
        usernameOrEmail: "support@auth0.com",
        password: "secret-password",
        realm: "Username-Password-Authentication",
        scope: "openid"
     )
     .start { result in
         switch result {
         case .success(let credentials):
            print("Obtained credentials: \(credentials)")
         case .failure(let error):
            print("Failed with \(error)")
         }
     }
```

**Sign up:**

```
Auth0.authentication()
     .createUser(
        email: "support@auth0.com",
        password: "secret-password",
        connection: "Username-Password-Authentication",
        userMetadata: ["first_name": "First",
                       "last_name": "Last"]
     )
     .start { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let user):
            print("User Signed up: \(user)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Failed with \(error)")
        }
     }
```

It is documented here: https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.swift#authentication-api-ios--macos--tvos

Comment: Thank you Tanver Hasan, may I know the realm: "Username-Password-Authentication",

Comment: Failed with Grant type 'http://auth0.com/oauth/grant-type/password-realm' not allowed for the client.

Comment: attempting to use any flow with an Application lacking the appropriate grant_types for that flow (or with the field empty) will result in the following error: Grant type `grant_type` not allowed for the client.
  https://auth0.com/docs/applications/application-grant-types#errors . In the application settings, you need to enable the appropriate grant type.https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant#realm-support

Comment: I enabled password grant type, because Username&password option not enabled.

Comment: When I open this link http://auth0.com/oauth/grant-type/password-realm I'm getting this error 404 Sorry, the page you were looking for doesn't exist.